# 2013th powered sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, contest-math

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, ... be a sequence of integers defined recursively by $a_1=2013$ and for $n \ge 1$, $a_{n+1}$ is the sum of the 2013th power of the digits of $a_n$. Do there exist distinct positive integers $i$, $j$ such that $a_i=a_j$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes because if $n$ is the number of digits, then
$$9^{2013}+9^{2013}+\ldots+9^{2013}=n\cdot9^{2013}<10^n$$
for sufficiently large $n$, above that point the number of digits won't increase anymore.

Can you fill in the details?